# Is it possible to entirely replace Lucenes MultiFieldQueryParser with Hibernate Search 6

Tags: spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I am about to migrate from Hibernate 5 to hibernate search 6 and are looking for some advice.
As I understand a main intention of the version 6 is to decouple the API more from the underlying implementation. I have something like this in my code:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory();
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = searchFactory.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Service.class).get();
BooleanJunction<?> bool = queryBuilder.bool();
Analyzer analyzer = searchFactory.getAnalyzer("standard");

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchString)) {
    MultiFieldQueryParser multiFieldQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] {
            "name", "description", "company.name", "configuration.name",
    }, analyzer);
    multiFieldQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParserBase.AND_OPERATOR);
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query querySearchString = multiFieldQueryParser.parse(searchString);
    bool.must(querySearchString);
}

Query fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(bool.createQuery(), Service.class);
return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

MultiFieldQueryParser, QueryParserBase and Query are classes from lucene backend.
Is it possible to realize the same query with pure hibernate search query syntax (Query DSL)?

I found simple examples for fields but could I use something like "company.name" for a related entity field annotated with @IndexedEmbedded ?

Thanks and best Regards
Matt

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. Something along the next lines:

```
searchSession.search( Service.class )
    .where( f -> f.and(
            f.match().field( "name" ).matching( searchString ),
            f.match().field( "description" ).matching( searchString )
            f.match().field( "company.name" ).matching( searchString )
    ) )
    .fetchHits( .. )
```

Look at the documentation for nested structure here - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-structure. There are examples of what you are looking for.
Also, it is recommended to take a look at the migration guide - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/. It contains a lot of helpful info on migration from 5 to 6

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, The migration guide I already know, for the other one I have looked within the Searching section not within the mapping section.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an exact equivalent to `MultiFieldQueryParser` in the Hibernate Search DSL (at least not yet: [HSEARCH-4563](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4563)). But there is an equivalent to the `SimpleQueryParser`, which *also* supports multiple fields, and might be enough *if you don't strictly need the Lucene query syntax* (since the query syntax is different): [`simpleQueryString`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-simple-query-string). The different syntax might be a good thing, since it's generally more understandable to end-users who are not experts in Lucene.

I'd suggest you try it out?

```java
searchSession.search( Service.class )
    .where( f -> f.simpleQueryString()
            .fields( "name", "description", "company.name" )
            .matching( searchString ),
            .defaultOperator( BooleanOperator.AND ) )
    .fetchHits( .. )
```

---

Regarding @mark_o's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76015662/6692043), while it gives you a behavior similar to `MultiFieldQueryParser`, it's not exactly the same, especially if the search string contains multiple terms:

- With `MultiFieldQueryParser`, not all fields need to match: what's important is that each term is matched by at least one field. With @mark_o's solution, each field must match at least one term.
- With `MultiFieldQueryParser`, all terms must be matched by at least one field. With @mark_o's solution, the query will match even if only one term is matched, by every field.